# How to display an image from an array of images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of object, with each object having an imageUrl property, but when I loop through this array to display all images, the image doesn't get rendered

I loop through the array and pass the attribute housing the image link to the image src

```
const ProjectData = [
  {
    title: "RestaurantX",
    imageUrl: "../assets/images/restaurantpassport.png",
    githubUrl: "",
    deployUrl: "",
    description: "",
    tech: []
  },
]
```

```
{ProjectData.map(project => {
            return (
             <Work borderColor={changeColor()}>
                <img
                  src={project.imageUrl}
                  alt={project.title}
                />
                <a className="github">
                  <i className="material-icons">code</i>
                </a>
                <a className="deploy">
                  <i className="material-icons">launch</i>
                </a>
              </Work>
            )
```

Comment: try making ProjectData to projectData

Comment: are you sure the url is correct?  Also in your example it doesn't look the the <Work> component is closed before returning.

Comment: You can't use relative paths (`../`) in an img src. You'll probably have to copy them in to a known folder in your output directory and then access them via `/knownfolder/filename.png`

Comment: it still doesn't work, I have converted ProjectData to projectData

Comment: tried removing `(../)` still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a relative path that points to somewhere in your project directory. Usual practice is to copy your images during your build process into a known folder in your output directory and then access them via `/knownfolder/filename.png` - the leading slash makes the path relative to the root of your app.

It isn't enough to just remove the `..` as your running app can't access your project folders at run-time.

As you are using `create-react-app`, you have (at least) two choices: 1) import the images using `import` or 2) Put them in your `/public` folder and use the `PUBLIC_URL` variable.

The first approach looks like this:

```
import restaurantPassport from '../assets/images/restaurantpassport.png'; 

<img src={restaurantPassport} />;
```

This is probably the one for you (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) for more detail), but if you want to go the other way it's covered [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) in the docs.

Comment: I really don't understand the approach, you are recommending

Comment: how is your app being bundled? are you using webpack?

Comment: This only works for few images right? What if I want to import multiple images? Like I can't write import for every image path in the object? Also if I copy all the images to the public folder, won't I have to add this public url thing again? I also saw that they recommend people to import images from src. But how do I do that for multiple images? Please help!

Comment: @Akhila - seems like you might need to ask a new question

Comment: Yeah after reading some more questions the only thing to do was to move the images that I'm dynamically loading to the public folder :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `require`.

Something like this -

```
const ProjectData = [
  {
    ...
    imageUrl: require("../assets/images/restaurantpassport.png"),
    ...
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply declare using `${restaurantpassport}` :

```
import restaurantpassport from "../assets/images/restaurantpassport.png"




 const ProjectData = [
  {
    title: "RestaurantX",
    imageUrl: `${restaurantpassport}`,
    githubUrl: "",
    deployUrl: "",
    description: "",
    tech: []
  },
]
```

{ProjectData.map(project => {
return (



code


launch


)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, in a way, I won't say is ideal, but works. I just had to make this change to `ProjectData array`.

```
  {
    title: "RestaurantX",
    imageUrl: require("../assets/images/restaurantpassport.png"),
    githubUrl: "",
    deployUrl: "",
    description: "",
    tech: []
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had the same issue.
I only added my image with a {} , but assind a backtick and dollar sign helped it display just like you did here:

```
    imageUrl: `${restaurantpassport}`
```