# How to get the path to a picture from an array?

Tags: reactjs

How to get the path to a picture from an array?

I try to do so, but the picture is not displayed, although the path is correct, what could be wrong?

```
  const arr = [
    { src: "../../../Assets/img/banner.jpg" }
  ];

  const onTest = () => {
    return arr.map((items, idx) => {
      return (
        <img 
          src={items.src}
          key={idx} 
          alt="test" 
        />
      )
    })
  };
```

Comment: What about if you try as `./Assets/img/banner.jpg` or `Assets/img/banner.jpg`?

Comment: No, the path is correct if I do: import banner from '../../../Assets/img/banner.jpg' 
then the picture appears

Comment: then to get it Dynamic you should do:
```{ src: Banner }```
instead of: ```{ src: "../../../Assets/img/banner.jpg" }```

Comment: Check this out, it might help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856500/how-to-display-an-image-from-an-array-of-images-in-react)